# Drag and Drop in multiple SVG canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a newbie here in coding world. I was playing with D3 and have a problem in drag-and-dropping circles in multiple SVG canvases. The circle won't drag after the first move in the first canvas. Moreover, the circles in other canvases are draggable but they changes in the unexpected manner. Could any of you take a look at this? Thank you much in advance. The following is the code:

```
svg_1 = d3.select("#svg1")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .style("background", "pink");
svg_2 = d3.select("#svg2")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .style("background", "pink");
svg_3 = d3.select("#svg3")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .style("background", "pink");
svg_4 = d3.select("#svg4")
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .style("background", "pink");

var initial = [{x:25, y:100}, {x:50, y:30}]
svg_1.selectAll("circle")
  .data(initial)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x })
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y })
  .classed("linear_control", true)
  .attr("r", 4)
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged))

svg_2.selectAll("circle")
  .data(initial)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x })
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y })
  .classed("linear_control", true)
  .attr("r", 4)
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged))

svg_3.selectAll("circle")
  .data(initial)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x })
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y })
  .classed("linear_control", true)
  .attr("r", 4)
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged))

svg_4.selectAll("circle")
  .data(initial)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x })
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y })
  .classed("linear_control", true)
  .attr("r", 4)
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged))

function dragged(d)
{
  d3.select(this)
  .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
  .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y)
}

dragged.d3.select(this)
```